# Entity Framework - Insert Object with multiple related objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, entity-framework

I'm trying to insert a new `[Shows]` record which has a 1-to-many relationship with `[Performances]` through a WCF service call.

The `[Shows]` record is created but the `[Performances]` records aren't. No error is thrown. How can I have the performance records created also?

**Client**

```
 Dim oShow As New Show With
            {
              'Properties here...
            }

    Dim cPerformances As New Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of Performance)

    cPerformances.Add(New Performance With
                      {
                          'Properties here...
                      })
    cPerformances.Add(New Performance With
                     {
                          'Properties here...
                     })

    oShow.Performances = cPerformances

        Dim myServiceRef As New myWCFService.ServiceName
        myServiceRef.CreateShow(oShow)
```

**Service**

```
        Dim ctx As New myEntities(ServiceURI)

        ctx.AddToShows(oShow)
        ctx.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: Do you see the performances properly populated on the Service side in the debugger, before calling SaveChanges()?

Comment: Yes, if I step through `ctx.AddToshows(oShow)` then all of the properties and the 2 Performance objects are there. Only the `Show` record is created.

Comment: You will have to manually create those as well maybe by from the Performance property.

Comment: @DonA - according to this link and every other thread I can find on it it should do this automatically - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546475/does-entity-framework-save-related-classes-automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the and recreated the edmx, the related objects are being inserted now.