# add object to context with related data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one class Game

```
 public class Game
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public User XUser { get; set; } = new User();
```

and other one User

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; } = "Computer";
}
```

On the page I have information about objects and can add new one

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Game) {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.XUser.UserName</td>
    </tr>
```

}
When i trying to add new object Game, I want that user name was rewrited

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        Game.XUser.UserName = "xxx";  // this is my string, but nothing has changed
        _context.Games.Add(Game);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

But I see always "Computer". I am new in FE, dont know what I m doing wrong?

#**ANSWER:
There is need UserId in the class Game**

```
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different classes for user and game...How you expect those to be overwrite ?

Comment: So how game class know about user has username Computer, I just want to overwrite this value and save it to database

Comment: If those two undefended classes you need to connect between those. You need to create a "linker" a third classes that stores the user and computer under same entity.

Comment: Why in this example there is no 3rd classes?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919948